# Dash change words in dcc.link

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I am writing in Python Dash. I would like to change the words in a dcc.Link dynamically.  This is my current link:

```
dcc.Link("Account", id='login_link', href='/login', style={'padding-left': '20px'})
```

I would like to change the word "Account" to "Logout" dynamically after logging in.  However, I can't find a property in dcc.Link for this.
https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/link

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the `children` prop. You can use a callback to change that based on some input. The docs specify that the first argument passed in, if unnamed, is always the `children` prop.