# Dynamically change dcc.link text

Tags: python, plotly-dash

My question is similar to the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68446584/dash-change-words-in-dcc-link).

I use a `dcc.link` as sign-in and sign-out button.

It means that I need to change the text dynamically corresponding to the authentication state (I use flask-login, i.e. `current_user.is_authenticated`)

My approach is to use a callback such that everytime the dcc.link is being clicked the authentication state is being checked. If someone has logged in the dcc link should read `sign out`. If noone has logged in it should read `sign in`. This is the callback I wrote:

```
@app.callback(
   Output(component_id='sign-in-out', component_property='children'),
   Input(component_id='sign-in-out', component_property='children'),
)
def show_hide_element(tmp):
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return "Sign out"
    else:
        return "Sign in"
```

Unfortunately this does not work as it should. When I click sign out it does not change the text accordingly. How could I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure that a property is allowed to update itself in a loop like this. You may need a different trigger.

Comment: what would be a workaround?

Comment: Using a different trigger as input